# How to set onClicklistener on recyclerview item in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am working on a project which requires display the list items using recycler view. Also each item must perform on click event. This is what I have done.

Fragment:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.stutee.bakingapp.utils.NetworkUtils;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URL;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class RecipeListFragment extends Fragment implements    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String> {

    private static final int LOADER_ID = 10;

    @BindView(R.id.rv_recipe_list) RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    public RecipeAdapter mAdapter;
    String[] parsedRecipeName;

    public RecipeListFragment() { }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable  ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipe_list, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this,rootView);

        mAdapter = new RecipeAdapter(getContext());

        int spanCount = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? 3 : 2;

        GridLayoutManager layoutManager

                = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),spanCount);



        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        Bundle bundleForLoader = new Bundle();

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, bundleForLoader,this);


        return rootView;
    }

@NonNull
@Override
public Loader<String> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
    return new AsyncTaskLoader<String>(getContext()) {

        String mRecipeJsonResult;

        @Override
        protected void onStartLoading() {
            if (mRecipeJsonResult != null) {
                deliverResult(mRecipeJsonResult);
            } else {

                forceLoad();
            }

        }



        @Override

        public String loadInBackground() {

            String s = "https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/59121517_baking/baking.json";
            URL recipeRequestUrl = NetworkUtils.buildUrl(s);

            try {

                String jsonRecipeResponse = NetworkUtils
                        .getResponseFromHttpUrl(recipeRequestUrl);

                return jsonRecipeResponse;
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                return null;
            }

        }

        public void deliverResult(String data) {

            mRecipeJsonResult = data;
            super.deliverResult(data);
        }

    };

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<String> loader, String data) {

    final String SHOW_NAME = "name";

    try {

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);

        parsedRecipeName = new String[jsonArray.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String recipeNameString = jsonObject.getString(SHOW_NAME);

            parsedRecipeName[i] = recipeNameString;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mAdapter.setRecipeName(parsedRecipeName);

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<String> loader) {

}
```

}

Adapter:

```
package com.example.stutee.bakingapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class RecipeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeAdapter.RecipeAdapterViewHolder> {

private String[] mRecipeName;

public interface RecipeAdapterOnClickHandler{
    void onClick(String name);
}

public RecipeAdapterOnClickHandler mClickHandler;

public RecipeAdapter(RecipeAdapterOnClickHandler clickHandler){
    mClickHandler = clickHandler;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecipeAdapter.RecipeAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.recipe_list_item;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, parent, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
    return new RecipeAdapterViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecipeAdapter.RecipeAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String currentRecipeName = mRecipeName[position];
    //Log.v(TAG, "poster path: " + currentPosterPath);
    holder.recipeNameTv.setText(currentRecipeName);
    }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (null == mRecipeName) return 0;
    return mRecipeName.length;
}

public class RecipeAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    @BindView(R.id.tv_recipe_name) TextView recipeNameTv;

    public RecipeAdapterViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
        String title = mRecipeName[adapterPosition];
        mClickHandler.onClick(title);
    }
}

public void setRecipeName(String[] recipeName) {
    mRecipeName = recipeName;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

I have made an interface in adapter to handle onClickListener and implemented it in MainActivity, the host activity of fragment. But it is not working.

Comment: Set onclicklistener to viewholder or the itemview that hold by the viewholder.

Answer (score 1):

onItemClickListener outside of the adapter.
first you need to create this class:

```
public class  RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
}

private OnItemClickListener mListener;
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

            if (childView != null && mListener != null) {
                mListener.onItemLongClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}
```

}

then you have to implement it like this

```
        recyclerViewClasses.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), recyclerViewClasses, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                RoundedImageView iv_student = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_student);
                TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
                textView.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {

                });

                iv_student.setOnClickListener(v -> {

                });
            }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a id for your layout item inside "R.layout.recipe_list_item".
Then Bind this id inside RecipeAdapterViewHolder.
Hence set listener in onBindViewHolder. Example
holder.(your_id_name).setOnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

defining onClick in the onBindViewHolder is not a good pratice

the correct way is that declare a interface in the adapter class and implement it on the Activity , Using interface we can pass the value

Steps 1: Decalre Listener for the OnItemClickListener interface

Step 2 : declare an interface , this interface will forward our click and data from adapter to our activity

Step3
Then define this interface in your fragment. 
Check code for full info https://github.com/Eldhopj/recyclerCardViewSample